# How to write a merge sort algorithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, bash, mergesort

I am trying to write the merge sort algorithm in Ruby. When I execute this script in bash, I get 'nil' in return. I am guessing that I need a set of numbers in the array so I placed "6,1,8,4,9,3" after "c=[...".

Here's the code:

```
def merge (a,b)
  index_a=0
  index_b=0
  c=[6,1,8,4,9,3]
  while index_a<a.length and index_b<b.length do
    if a[index_a]<=b[index_b] then
      c<<a[index_a]
      index_a=index_a+1
    else
      c<<b[index_b]
      index_b=index_b+1
    end
  end

  if(index_a<a.length) then
    for i in(index_a..a.length-1) do
      c<<a[i]
    end
  else
    for i in(index_b..b.length-1) do
      c<<b[i]
    end
  end

  return c
end

def msort(list)
  return list if list.length==1 #base cases
  halfway=list.length/2
  list1=list[0..halfway-1]
  list2=list[halfway..list.length-1]
  newlist1=msort(list1) #recursive!
  newlist2=msort(list2) #recursive!
  newlist=merge(newlist1,newlist2)
  return newlist
end
```

And for reference, I got this from a CMU [lecture slide](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15110-f12/Unit05PtC-handout.pdf).

Comment: Your code only defined two methods but it didn't actually do anything; please show the entire ruby script including how you called the methods.  Also, you should be able to narrow down the problem yourself more than just saying it returns nil.  Why did it return nil?

Comment: What's the significance of `[6,1,8,4,9,3]`?  That shouldn't be there in a general-purpose sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The `c=[]` line was correct. Keep it the way it was.

The `merge` method is for merging together 2 sorted arrays, `a` and `b`. It is used by the sort algorithm in `msort`.

It's `msort` that should take the unsorted array as a parameter. So call it by putting

```
p msort([6,1,8,4,9,3])
```

at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergesort(container)
  return container if container.size <= 1
  mid   = container.size / 2
  left  = container[0...mid]
  right = container[mid...container.size]
  merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
end

def merge(left, right)
  sorted = []
  until left.empty? or right.empty?
    sorted << (left.first <= right.first ? left.shift : right.shift)
  end
  sorted + left + right
end
```